# Detach disk from virtual machine using the new Azure Resource Manager API

Tags: .net, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rest-api

I struggle to port my automated Azure VM management from the old .NET fluent API to the new ARM API (the one in the `Azure.ResourceManager.*` namespaces).

The most important point is detaching a disk from a VM.

The `VirtualMachineResource` has only one `UpdateAsync` method, and that is taking a `VirtualMachinePatch`. I could successfully attach a disk that was previously unattached by using this patch object:

```cs
        var vmPatch = new VirtualMachinePatch
        {
            StorageProfile = new VirtualMachineStorageProfile
            {
                DataDisks =
                {
                    new VirtualMachineDataDisk(0, DiskCreateOptionType.Attach)
                    {
                        ManagedDisk = new VirtualMachineManagedDisk
                        {
                            Id = disc.Id
                        },
                        DeleteOption = DiskDeleteOptionType.Detach
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

It's not obvious how detaching is supposed to work though, and the documentation is sparse. Simply leaving the `DataDisks` property empty does nothing, as one would expect.

The old fluent API had specialized methods, allowing to write something like

```cs
    vm.Update().WithoutDataDisk(entry.Lun);
```

The new one, is far less obvious to use. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct way of doing this by looking at the .NET SDK test suite:

```
        var vmPatch = new VirtualMachinePatch
        {
            StorageProfile = new VirtualMachineStorageProfile
            {
                DataDisks =
                {
                    new VirtualMachineDataDisk(0, DiskCreateOptionType.Attach)
                    {
                        ToBeDetached = true
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

A bit obvious in hindsight, but I missed it several time.